# Determine which remote branches can be safely deleted

Tags: git

I have a bunch of remote git branches:

`remotes/origin/<branchname>` etc...

I know most of them can probably be deleted.

1. What's the best way to see which ones have been fully merged into master? These I want to delete first.
2. What's the best way to see the unmerged commits for the rest of the branches?

Comment: I'd like to amend that for github repos the the "branches" tab will let you switch between showing merged and unmerged branches. Each branch also has a delete button next to it. It think this might be the fastest way to manage these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does `git branch -r --merged master` do what you want?

Comment: And the counterpart `--no-merged`... I like that better than the answer I gave...

Answer (score 1):

One way to get this info would be:

```
git branch -vv
```

That will list whether each branch is up-to-date, ahead or behind, but it's designed for humans to read, so it's not easily parseable for further scripting. There might be better ways if you need to take that route.

Taking a look in one of the GUIs could tell you visually what branches aren't merged, as well, but depending on how many branches you have, that might be tedious.

Edit: Another option would be this:

```
git show-branch --independent | xargs git name-rev
```

That essentially shows what branches are not reachable from any of the other branches, but might also include `master` on the list, so you might need to prune the output a bit...

Answer (score 0):

This `git log` command is what I use to see how the branches relate to each other.

> log --oneline --decorate=short --graph --all --simplify-by-decoration

and to add the undecorated commits to the above just remove the `--simplify-by-decoration`

> log --oneline --decorate=short --graph --all

Also, not directly an answer to your question, but related to seeing what commits need attention, this version shows just the commits on branches with romote tracking that have not been pushed.

> log --oneline --decorate=short --graph --all --branches --not --remotes

Answer (score 0):

My first choice would be just to try deleting it with `git branch -d` (lower case d).  That will fail if the branch hasn't been fully merged in.